# Why is it necessary to use schema.StateUpgrader.Type when implementing State Upgraders in Terraform SDKv2?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: writing a migration by following Resources - [State Migration article](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/resources/state-migration).

There's this code snippet:

```
        StateUpgraders: []schema.StateUpgrader{
            {
                Type:    resourceExampleInstanceResourceV0().CoreConfigSchema().ImpliedType(),
                Upgrade: resourceExampleInstanceStateUpgradeV0,
                Version: 0,
            },
        },
    }
}

func resourceExampleInstanceResourceV0() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "name": {
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
            },
        },
    }
}

func resourceExampleInstanceStateUpgradeV0(rawState map[string]interface{}, meta interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    rawState["name"] = rawState["name"] + "."

    return rawState, nil
}
```

but essentially `resourceExampleInstanceStateUpgradeV0` takes a map and returns an updated map, how does it use `Type:    resourceExampleInstanceResourceV0().CoreConfigSchema().ImpliedType()`?

The docs say:

```
    // Type describes the schema that this function can upgrade. Type is
    // required to decode the schema if the state was stored in a legacy
    // flatmap format.
    Type cty.Type
```

Is using `flatmap` format still a thing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK here is reflecting some details of the underlying protocol, so I think answering this will require some background information on the protocol.

Terraform Core calls the SDK logic you're referring to by calling the [`UpgradeResourceState`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/ec4935ba5db516ebe24bf2d26a31fcd2db518b5d/docs/plugin-protocol/tfplugin6.2.proto#L191-L216) RPC function, whose request includes a [`RawState`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/ec4935ba5db516ebe24bf2d26a31fcd2db518b5d/docs/plugin-protocol/tfplugin6.2.proto#L66-L72) message that describes the data from the state.

> ```
> // RawState holds the stored state for a resource to be upgraded by the
> // provider. It can be in one of two formats, the current json encoded format
> // in bytes, or the legacy flatmap format as a map of strings.
> message RawState {
>     bytes json = 1;
>     map<string, string> flatmap = 2;
> }
> ```

In all other situations where Terraform Core sends resource data to a provider it uses a [`DynamicValue`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/ec4935ba5db516ebe24bf2d26a31fcd2db518b5d/docs/plugin-protocol/tfplugin6.2.proto#L24-L29) message instead, which contains serialized forms of the resource object that Terraform Core already processed using the schema, and therefore Terraform Core can guarantee it will be of a shape conforming to the current schema for the corresponding resource type.

> ```
> // DynamicValue is an opaque encoding of terraform data, with the field name
> // indicating the encoding scheme used.
> message DynamicValue {
>     bytes msgpack = 1;
>     bytes json = 2;
> }
> ```

This difference arises because Terraform Core only has access to the *current* schema for each resource type defined in the provider, but the upgrade action by definition works with data conforming to an older schema that Terraform Core doesn't know. Therefore for this particular operation the provider recieves exactly the data that was stored in the state, verbatim in whatever form it was stored. That could either be a raw JSON serialization or it could be the legacy "flatmap" format, depending on which version of Terraform created the most recent state snapshot.

The SDK chooses to normalize away this difference between raw JSON or flatmap by doing its own decoding of the raw data using a schema, but that means it needs to have a copy of the old schema in order to do so. You can see the relevant logic in [the SDK's implementation of `UpgradeResourceState`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/4681738a561387fb0b3aaa69aeb42231383634a0/helper/schema/grpc_provider.go#L295-L329).

The SDK could alternatively have just exposed the raw data to the upgrade function and left the provider developer to decide how to deal with it, but the old SDK's priority is to preserve compatibility with the legacy protocol used by Terraform v0.11 and earlier and so it has this additional level of abstraction to help ensure that the same upgrade function can always handle both serialization formats.

As you noted, modern Terraform never uses the "flatmap" form of resource data and so a provider that doesn't need to be able to upgrade gracefully from a state snapshot created with Terraform v0.11 could potentially just return an error if asked to upgrade a flatmap state. If a particular provider never supported the Terraform v0.11 form of the provider protocol (protocol version 4) then there should be no way for such a state to exist, and therefore reasonable to reject it. The team working on the newer Terraform Plugin Framework made a similar observation and so that newer API [exposes the `RawState` message directly](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/tfsdk#UpgradeResourceStateRequest), and leaves it up to the provider developer to decide how to handle it, but does also allow *optionally* providing a prior schema to get a more convenient API for interacting with the prior state.